# How does the comma operator in Javascript work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have come across a jQuery/Javascript statement that I don't understand. It involves the "comma operator". I looked it up, but I don't see a good explanation with a good example.

Here is the statement:

```
var nav = $( '#site-navigation' ), button, menu;
```

Comment: It's not the comma operator, but rather a part of the `var` statement syntax. The comma acts as a separator between separate variables being declared. (There *is* a comma operator, however; it's just that this isn't an example of the comma operator.)

Comment: What do you exactly want to know? That's simply how the syntax of the variable declaration statement is. It works the way it does because the specification defines what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an operator. The comma allows you to define more than one variable with a single `var` statement:

```
var nav = $( '#site-navigation' ), // define variable 'nav' and assign $( '#site-navigation' ) to it
    button, // this defines variable named 'button' with no initial value 
    menu; // this defines variable named 'menu' with no initial value
```

The comma operator is something else - you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: In addition: your example defines 3 new vars in stead of one: nav, button and menu

Comment: @Gumbo: This is not the comma operator, it's how the variable declaration statement is defined: http://es5.github.io/#x12.2.

Comment: @Gumbo it is an operator, but it also servers a separate purpose in a `var` statement. This is not an example of the comma operator in action, in other words.

Comment: @FelixKling You’re right, sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Using the comma in that context:

```
var nav = $( '#site-navigation' ), button, menu;
```

is "shorthand" for...

```
var nav = $( '#site-navigation' );
var button;
var menu;
```